# SharePoint Master Page not styling links

Tags: css, sharepoint, master-pages, sharepoint-designer

I built a Master Page using SharePoint Designer 2010 which references an external stylesheet like so:

`<link href="/sites/sandbox/Style%20Library/pscp/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

In the design mode of the master page, all of the styles are reflected correctly, likewise when I create a new .aspx based on that master page. However, when I preview the .aspx on Internet Explorer, all of the styles work except for the ones that apply to styling `<a href>` elements (for example, hover, color, etc.).

Adding the styles in-line to the `<a href>` elements in the master page make it so that they are reflected in the preview of the .aspx, but if I add the styles pertaining to links at the top of the master page using `<styles>` tags, it stops working, too.

Anyone have any ideas as to why styling links with an external stylesheet doesn't seem to work? Thank you in advance.

Comment: SIGH, turns out that Internet Explorer was in compatibility mode, so when I put it in normal mode, the styles would show up correctly. Whoops.

Answer (score 0):

there are quite a few ways to reference your resources

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="/Style Library/OVERRIDE.css" After="COREV4.css" runat="server"/>
```

be careful on testing on IE because often you will experience cache on the browser, cache on the load balancers, and the compatibility mode, which you can disable for yourself, but remember other users still have it enabled